# In suse linux, how do I control where a new window will pop up?

Tags: windows, window-manager

Linux and Unix have always sought an open area on the desktop to open a popup window.  In these days of dual monitors, this can be very annoying.  How can I force a pop up, like an "Open file" window to open over the application?